# In expectation maximization, why do we have a latent variable distribution for every sample of the data

Tags: probability, expectation-maximization, latent-variable

I am reading this blog on expectation maximization - http://krasserm.github.io/2019/11/21/latent-variable-models-part-1/

Starting the section where the author starts explaining how EM is done in the most general form, he writes

[image]

Specifically at this point I have a question. Why do we have a distribution over the latent variables for every data point i? I thought there is a one prior distribution q over the variable t which generates the points. So in my intuition I see nature picking one of the (gaussians?) from q (gives a specific t) and then using that (gaussian?) nature generates the data xi.

If my intuition is correct then why do we index q with i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $q(\cdot)$ is *not* indexed by $i$.